# Ignite QueryEntity without index

Tags: ignite

I want to set QueryEntity with indexes in ignite configuration but it is not allowing to set. I am using 2.9.0. If I dont set indexes then it does not create then It doesn't create tables. If I try to set then it throws exception mentioned in below link.

[Getting Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryInvalidTypeException: in ignite 2.9.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64641660/getting-caused-by-class-org-apache-ignite-binary-binaryinvalidtypeexception-in/)

Can anyone tell me how to set query entity without indices?

Comment: Did you add `ignite-indexing` to classpath?

Comment: yes.I have added that.

Comment: Then you should not get that exception. Please provide full exception message and stack trace as well as cache configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I do not understand, but I am trying this right from documentation, and it works:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
       xsi:schemaLocation="
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util.xsd">

    <bean id="ignite.cfg" class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.IgniteConfiguration">
        <property name="cacheConfiguration">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.apache.ignite.configuration.CacheConfiguration">
                    <property name="name" value="mycache"/>
                    <!-- Configure query entities -->
                    <property name="queryEntities">
                        <list>
                            <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryEntity">
                                <!-- Setting indexed type's key class -->
                                <property name="keyType" value="java.lang.Long"/>

                                <!-- Setting indexed type's value class -->
                                <property name="valueType" value="org.apache.ignite.examples.Person"/>

                                <!-- Defining fields that will be either indexed or queryable. Indexed fields are added to 'indexes' list below.-->
                                <property name="fields">
                                    <map>
                                        <entry key="id" value="java.lang.Long"/>
                                        <entry key="name" value="java.lang.String"/>
                                        <entry key="salary" value="java.lang.Long "/>
                                    </map>
                                </property>

                                <!-- Defining indexed fields.-->
                                <property name="indexes">
                                    <list>
                                        <!-- Single field (aka. column) index -->
                                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                                            <constructor-arg value="id"/>
                                        </bean>

                                        <!-- Group index. -->
                                        <bean class="org.apache.ignite.cache.QueryIndex">
                                            <constructor-arg>
                                                <list>
                                                    <value>id</value>
                                                    <value>salary</value>
                                                </list>
                                            </constructor-arg>
                                            <constructor-arg value="SORTED"/>
                                        </bean>
                                    </list>
                                </property>
                            </bean>
                        </list>
                    </property>
                </bean>
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Can you show your configuration?

Comment: remove indexes section and then check with 2.9.0

Comment: @ilya / Dipak - Could you please put more light on this value in config?   value="org.apache.ignite.examples.Person"     - How do I do the configuration if I want to define a new query entity for e.g. Employee?

Answer (score 0):

Issue got resolved . While setting QueryEntity key fields and fields in QueryEntity are required to set.